# polarimetric imager in python

Tags: python, beginner, opencv

My code takes 3 images taken with a polarising filter rotated 45° between them and transform them into a single image encoding the polarization parameters as HSV. what can be improved?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image 
from IPython.display import Image
%matplotlib inline
import glob
import math    
imagefiles=glob.glob(r"C:\Users\HP\My Python stuff\openCV\Polarization\IMG*")
imagefiles.sort()
images=[]
for filename in imagefiles:
    img=cv2.imread(filename)
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    images.append(img)
num_images=len(images)
pixel0x,pixel0y,pixel0z=cv2.split(images[0])
pixel45x,pixel45y,pixel45z=cv2.split(images[1])
pixel90x,pixel90y,pixel90z=cv2.split(images[2])
i0 =  pixel0x * 0.3 +  pixel0y * 0.59 +  pixel0z * 0.11
i45 = pixel45x * 0.3 + pixel45y * 0.59 + pixel45z * 0.11
i90 = pixel90x * 0.3 + pixel90y * 0.59 + pixel90z * 0.11
stokesI = i0 + i90
stokesQ = i0 - i90
stokesU = (np.ones(stokesI.shape)*(2.0 * i45))- stokesI
polint = np.sqrt(stokesQ*stokesQ+stokesU*stokesU)
poldolp = polint/(stokesI+((np.ones(stokesI.shape)*0.001)))
polaop = 0.5 * np.arctan(stokesU, stokesQ)
h=(polaop+(np.ones(polaop.shape)*(3.1416/2.0)))/3.1416
s=poldolp
v=polint
hsvpolar=cv2.merge((h,s,v))
hsvpolar=np.multiply(hsvpolar, 255)
rgbimg = cv2.cvtColor(np.clip(hsvpolar, 0,255).astype('uint8'),cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgbimg)
cv2.imwrite("hsvpolarized.jpg",rgbimg)
```

these are the input images:
[image: input images]

Comment: Please embed sample input images, and show all of your imports

Comment: That's... Not really what I meant. The images need to be separate and not in a combined screenshot, so that we can feed them to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not great use of Numpy - for instance, rather than writing your coefficients out in triplicate, this needs to be a single tensor dot product. `ones()` is never called for in this program if you correctly use broadcasting.

Put your code in functions.

Don't hard-code system-specific file paths.

Prefer `pathlib` over `os`, for `glob` etc.

Don't write a (truncated) literal for pi; instead write `np.pi`.

Most importantly, your results are basically nonsense because the images don't only change polarisation - they change alignment. You need to apply a matching, homography and perspective de-warp to your images for this to make any sense, and OpenCV offers these to you out of the box. The demonstration code below follows https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html .

### Suggested

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def warp_align(images: list[np.ndarray]) -> None:
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    keys: list[tuple] = []
    descriptors: list[np.ndarray] = []
    for image in images:
        key, descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute(image, mask=None)
        keys.append(key)
        descriptors.append(descriptor)

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(
        indexParams={'algorithm': FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, 'trees': 5},
        searchParams={'checks': 50},
    )

    LOWES_RATIO = 0.7
    train_desc, *query_descs = descriptors
    matches = [
        [
            m
            for m, n in flann.knnMatch(query_desc, train_desc, k=2)
            if m.distance < LOWES_RATIO*n.distance
        ]
        for query_desc in query_descs
    ]

    def keys_to_points(matched_keys: Iterable[tuple[float, float]]) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.array(tuple(matched_keys), dtype=np.float32)

    train_key, *query_keys = keys
    for query_key, target_matches, image in zip(query_keys, matches, images[1:]):
        query_points = keys_to_points(query_key[m.queryIdx].pt for m in target_matches)
        train_points = keys_to_points(train_key[m.trainIdx].pt for m in target_matches)
        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(query_points, train_points, method=cv2.RANSAC, ransacReprojThreshold=5)
        print(M, '\n')
        cv2.warpPerspective(src=image, dst=image, M=M, dsize=image.shape[1::-1])


def calculate_polarimetry(images: list[np.ndarray]) -> np.ndarray:
    all_images = np.stack(images)
    coefficients = np.array((0.30, 0.59, 0.11))
    i00, i45, i90 = np.tensordot(all_images,  coefficients, axes=[3, 0])

    stokes_i = i00 + i90
    stokes_q = i00 - i90
    stokes_u = 2*i45 - stokes_i

    polint = np.sqrt(stokes_q*stokes_q + stokes_u*stokes_u)
    poldolp = polint/(stokes_i + 0.001)
    polaop = 0.5 * np.arctan(stokes_u, stokes_q)

    h = polaop/np.pi + 0.5
    s = poldolp
    v = polint

    hsv_polar = 255*np.clip(cv2.merge((h, s, v)), 0, 1)
    return cv2.cvtColor(hsv_polar.astype('uint8'), cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)


def main() -> None:
    paths = sorted(Path.cwd().glob("pol*.png"))
    images = [
        cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(str(path)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        for path in paths
    ]
    warp_align(images)
    rgb_img = calculate_polarimetry(images)

    fig, ((tl, tr), (bl, br)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
    tl.imshow(images[0])
    tr.imshow(images[1])
    bl.imshow(images[2])
    br.imshow(rgb_img)
    plt.show()
    # cv2.imwrite("hsvpolarized.jpg", rgbimg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Prior to homographic correction

[image: noncorrected]

### After homographic correction

[image: corrected]

Comment: The result is not nonsense. They do change polarization. The images are taken strapping a polarising filter to the camera, aligning it to horizontal polarization, taking a picture. Then rotating it 45°, taking another picture and then rotating again and taking the third picture, as described in https://hackaday.io/project/6958-dolpi-raspi-polarization-camera

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood what I mean. The polarisation is important, and spatial displacement is not - so any serious analysis of polarisation requires that the spatial displacement be removed; otherwise the results will not make sense.

Comment: Ohhh. Yes! You're absolutely right. I thought you meant that there was no polarization information in the images. That's why I explained how they were acquired. Sorry