# Polarimetric imaging script in python

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I made this script that takes 3 images taken with a polarising filter 45° apart as inputs and outputs an RGB preview and an image which encodes the polarization parameters as HSV.

However it's way too slow, taking 155.8125 seconds to process it. What can I do to improve it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image 
from IPython.display import Image
import glob
import math
from pystackreg import StackReg
def isolateblue(image):
    r,g,b=cv2.split(image)
    return b
def rgb_preview(imagelist):
    return cv2.merge((imagelist[2],imagelist[1],imagelist[0])).astype('uint8')
def hsv_processing(imagelist):
    i0 =imagelist[0]/1
    i45 =imagelist[1]/1
    i90 =imagelist[1]/1
    stokesI = i0 + i90
    stokesQ = i0 - i90
    stokesU = (np.ones(stokesI.shape)*(2.0 * i45))- stokesI
    polint = np.sqrt(stokesQ*stokesQ+stokesU*stokesU)
    poldolp = polint/(stokesI+((np.ones(stokesI.shape)+0.001)))
    polaop = 0.5 * np.arctan(stokesU, stokesQ)
    h=(polaop+(np.ones(polaop.shape)*(np.pi/2.0)))/np.pi
    s=poldolp*200
    s[s<0]=0
    s[s>255]=255
    v=polint
    hsvpolar=cv2.merge((h,s,v))
    rgbimg = cv2.cvtColor(hsvpolar.astype('uint8'),cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)*2
    rgbimg[rgbimg<0]=0
    rgbimg[rgbimg>255]=255
    return rgbimg
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imagefiles=glob.glob(r"#whatever your filepath is")
    imagefiles.sort()
    images=[]
    for filename in imagefiles:
      img=cv2.imread(filename)
      img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      img=np.int16(img)
      images.append(img)
    polchannels=[]
    for image in images:
        polchannels.append(isolateblue(image))
    num_images=len(polchannels)
    sr=StackReg(StackReg.AFFINE)
    polchannels=sr.register_transform_stack(np.stack((polchannels[0],polchannels[1],polchannels[2])), reference='first')
    cv2.imwrite("rgb preview.jpg",rgb_preview(polchannels))
    cv2.imwrite("polarimetric image.jpg",hsv_processing(polchannels))
    print("done")
```

Associated files (Google Drive):

- [(high resolution) inputs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13_hUAFGEuV6No-488LiCtdhVt6ntLRCq)
- [outputs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13cYeNRHhonD0l3tQtTABFJnzrqMGH7DI)

Comment: This is a continuation of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280251/polarimetric-imager-in-python

Comment: Have you done any profiling? Your program is taking forever because StackReg itself is taking forever.

Comment: Surely `i90 = imagelist[1]` should be `i90 = imagelist[2]`; you're throwing away a channel otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to care about correctness before performance, and (though it's difficult to say for sure because your numerical methods are undocumented), it's highly unlikely that the output is correct. But, from the top:

You need blank lines in your source. No, seriously. Listen to a PEP8 linter.

`isolateblue` does not need `cv2` and can use a Numpy slice directly. Further to that, though: `images` should not be a list, and instead should be a single Numpy pre-allocated array that receives only the blue channels of each image loaded.

`int16` is not necessary here.

`StackReg` is slow. But (unlike your previous test images), these images are well aligned enough that you might get away with not aligning them at all. If you need to preserve this step, the approach I already showed you in the previous question of using OpenCV's own homography algorithm is about four times as fast as `StackReg`, and drops one external dependency.

Don't cast arrays to `float` by using `/1`. Use `.astype()`.

`i90 =imagelist[1]` should certainly pull from the third channel `[2]` and not the second `[1]`.

Stop calling `np.ones` when you should just broadcast. It was a habit in your previous question, it's a habit here, and you need to break it. You've managed to introduce a numerical error because of it: when you write `np.ones(stokesI.shape)+0.001`, that add should have been a multiply; but really the entire `ones()` call should go away.

Don't `s[s>255]=255`; use `np.clip()`.

`cv2.merge` is really just a `np.stack()`.

Don't post-multiply `cvtColor` by 2. If you need brighter colours, multiply the value channel.

Your hue calculation is probably incorrect. After you divide out pi, you need to multiply by 180, since OpenCV's HSV colour space has H ranging from 0 through 180.

### Suggested

```
from typing import Iterable

import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np


BLUE_CHANNEL = 0


def warp_align(images: np.ndarray) -> None:
    print('SIFT detect and compute...')
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    keys: list[tuple] = []
    descriptors: list[np.ndarray] = []
    for image in images:
        key, descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute(image, mask=None)
        keys.append(key)
        descriptors.append(descriptor)

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(
        indexParams={'algorithm': FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, 'trees': 5},
        searchParams={'checks': 50},
    )

    print('knn match...')
    LOWES_RATIO = 0.7
    train_desc, *query_descs = descriptors
    matches = [
        [
            m
            for m, n in flann.knnMatch(query_desc, train_desc, k=2)
            if m.distance < LOWES_RATIO*n.distance
        ]
        for query_desc in query_descs
    ]

    def keys_to_points(matched_keys: Iterable[tuple[float, float]]) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.array(tuple(matched_keys), dtype=np.float32)

    print('Dewarping with homographies...')
    train_key, *query_keys = keys
    for query_key, target_matches, image in zip(query_keys, matches, images[1:]):
        query_points = keys_to_points(query_key[m.queryIdx].pt for m in target_matches)
        train_points = keys_to_points(train_key[m.trainIdx].pt for m in target_matches)
        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(query_points, train_points, method=cv2.RANSAC, ransacReprojThreshold=5)
        print(M)
        cv2.warpPerspective(src=image, dst=image, M=M, dsize=image.shape[::-1])


def rgb_preview(image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Convert from (rgb), x, y to x, y, (bgr)"""
    return np.moveaxis(image, 0, -1)[..., ::-1]


def hsv_processing(image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    i00, i45, i90 = image
    i00 = i00.astype(float)

    stokesI = i00 + i90
    stokesQ = i00 - i90
    stokesU = 2*i45 - stokesI

    polint = np.sqrt(stokesQ*stokesQ + stokesU*stokesU)
    # In [0, inf]
    poldolp = polint/(stokesI + 1e-6)
    # In [-pi/2, pi/2]
    polaop = np.arctan(stokesU, stokesQ)

    h = (polaop/np.pi + 0.5)*180
    s = np.clip(100*poldolp, a_min=0, a_max=255)
    v = np.clip(2*polint, a_min=0, a_max=255)
    hsvpolar = np.stack((h, s, v), axis=-1).astype('uint8')
    return cv2.cvtColor(hsvpolar, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)


def main() -> None:
    print('Loading images...')
    image_filenames = glob.glob('Test*degrees.jpg')
    image_filenames.sort()

    pol_channels = None

    for i, filename in enumerate(image_filenames):
        img = cv2.imread(filename)  # BGR
        if pol_channels is None:
            pol_channels = np.empty((3, *img.shape[:2]), dtype=np.uint8)
        pol_channels[i, ...] = img[..., BLUE_CHANNEL]

    warp_align(pol_channels)
    print('Generating preview...')
    cv2.imwrite("rgb preview.jpg", rgb_preview(pol_channels))
    print('Generating polarimetry...')
    cv2.imwrite("polarimetric image.jpg", hsv_processing(pol_channels))
    print('Done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

[image: rgb preview]

[image: polarimetry]

Comment: That add is there to avoid division by zero, I'm sure it's not a multiplication.

Comment: I do use a linter. Bandit is my go-to because it identifies security issues: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Re. multiplication - look closer. You should be adding a product but instead you're adding a sum.

Comment: Re. linter: whatever you're using, it isn't enough. You need a whitespace linter.